# git commands hang and finish after >1 minute in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Yesterday git commands (e.g. `git pull`) started to be super slow, when doing them against gitlab.com. They are working as usual when using them against github.com, so I assumed this is a problem with gitlab.com.

After waiting a couple of days, and not seeing any reports on the gitlab status page, I conclude this is related to my setup somehow.

I've added some debug logs and seeing this happens after the following command:

```
20:47:50.705689 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; ssh git@gitlab.com 'git-upload-pack
```

I also tried to delete and re-clone my repo, but that didn't help either.

EDIT:
On a different wifi network it works normally. What the hell.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the router worked. Go figure.